Casting covariant interface refrences fails
I have a covariant interface:
Here is my generic covariant interface:
public interface IColumn<TGridRow, out TProp>
{
    Func<TGridRow, TProp> ValueSelector { get; }
}

My implementation of that interface:
public class Column<TGridRow, TProp>(Func<TGridRow, TProp> valueSelector) : IColumn<TGridRow, TProp>
{
    public Func<TGridRow, TProp> ValueSelector => valueSelector;


}

I Expect to cast:
I expect conversion from IColumn<Person, int> to IColumn<Person, object> be possible as int derives from object and IColumn<> is covariant on its second type argument.
Error I get:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Column2[Person,System.Int32]' to type 'IColumn2[Person,System.Object]'.'

Sample Casting that fails:
var column = new Column<Person, int>(p => p.Age);
IColumn<Person, int> referenceConverted = (IColumn<Person, int>)column;
IColumn<Person, object> referenceConverted2 = (IColumn<Person, object>)referenceConverted;

Why isn't working as expected?

"as int derives from object" no it doesn't.

Built-in types (C# reference)

@JeremyLakeman "C#’s type system is unified such that a value of any type can be treated as an object. Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type" from language specifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#81-general

Value types can be boxed into an object, and implement the object interface. But that doesn't make them objects.

@JeremyLakeman I see your point, It's correct and it actually targets the issue I asked about. My point is  that the "goal of design" was that everything could be treated as an object. Seems to me current behavior of covariance/contravariant does not comply with it.
